# Merge Lists and return only duplicates

Tags: c#, linq, list, merge, duplicates

Say I've got two lists:

```
List<string>foo=new List<string>();
List<string>bar=new List<string>();
```

I want to merge these two lists and return another list with only the duplicates in the both.

So if I have:

```
//pseudocode
foo={"baz","lemons","somethingelse"}
bar={"what","another","baz","somethingelse","kitten"}
```

I want it to return a new List:

```
//pseudocode
dupes={"baz","somethingelse"}
```

I think using LINQ will be the best shot. However, I haven't quite figured that since I have poor LINQ experience.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`Intersect` is what you want which is part of LINQ.

```
dupes = foo.Intersect(bar).ToList();
```

Ensure you have the `System.Linq` namespace referenced in your file.

Answer (score 3):

You want an "Intersect" of the two sets.

```
dupes = foo.Intersect(bar);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use intersection:

```
var res = lst1.Intersect(lst2);
```